# Odoo/Open ERP Customer Wizard

Tags: odoo, openerp-8, odoo-8

I'm new to Odoo and I need some help. I've created a wizard to be displayed on the res.partner page which lists/shows all of the customers. However, I don't know what addon folder to add the wizard.

I realize that I have to create my init file, but that's easy once I know where this is supposed to go. Any thoughts would be greatly helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) You can use existing "partner" or "partner/wizard" directory... Just add `import your_custom_wiz` to same directory and append `'your_custom_wiz_view.xml'` to **openerp**.py in `'update_xml':` list

OR

(2) add your own addons direcotry contining your custom "partner" module, where you can put your wizard. Note that this option mean that you will have to:

- add your addons dir to openerp .conf file as `addons_path = /home/some_user/your_installation_directory/odoo_8.0/openerp/my_addons,`
- install your custom "partner" module to db

Second (2) option is better and more accurate